# Reusable Class - Using "abstract" instead of pre-defined

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am building an application where there are multiple classes that inherit from a single base class. Let's say I have this declaration:

```
ref class WorkScreenBase abstract
{
internal:
   WorkScreenBase(void);
   bool isLoaded;
}
```

I have several classes that implement it, for example:

```
ref class MainScreen : public WorkScreenBase
{
internal:
   MainScreen(void);
   ~MainScreen(void);
}
```

In another part of the application, I want to have a container for any potential implementation of `WorkScreenBase`, so I am trying to use:

```
WorkScreenBase^ myCurrentBase;
```

However, it appears that this would be illegal. What would be the best way to approach the problem?

**UPDATE:** I could use a `MainScreen^ myCurrentScreen`, but would much rather use the base class as the reference point for flexibility reasons.

Comment: Why do you say "it appears that this would be illegal"?

Comment: `WorkScreenBase^ myCurrentBase` is illegal syntax in C++. Removed the C++ tag. Maybe this is C++-CLI or some other non-C++ language?

Comment: There is a "missing type specifier" thrown on this line. As I understand, I cannot keep it as an object for obvious reasons (abstract class), so I am wondering what might be the issue.

Comment: What is the exact error (with error number) and can you provide a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem?  It sounds like you are missing an include file or are forgetting to qualify the name with its namespace (those are just guesses; without seeing real code, it's hard to say for sure).

Comment: Are you declaring the attribute (myCurrentBase) as public or internal? if you are declaring in as public in the base class you need to make it a property.

Comment: It is internal.

@JamesMcNellis my thoughts were the same, but apparently the class is recognized (e.g. on hover) and if I remove ^, I get an exception telling me that I cannot have an object of an abstract type. The current error is C4430.

Comment: Is your code materially different from this:  https://gist.github.com/f81a8e8eb3e4ed88f448?  I don't have the Visual Studio 2012 RC installed, but that _should_ work.  If you can provide a standalone repro, it would be much easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It is very close to that, the declaration being in the header, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in a way that I did not expect (at least according to the compiler error thrown). The problem was in the header file cross-reference. Somehow, both with header guards and `#pragma once`, I ended up with a circular **.h** reference.

So, **conclusion**:

- The compiler can throw errors that might not exactly describe the
  problem.
- Double-check the headers for circular references. Headers guards and `#pragma once` are good, but won't help you against that.